# how to create and insert data from a list into a hibernate query

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I need to create a temporary table with hibernate and then insert data from a list into this table. here is what I mean :

```
String hql = "create temporary table temp (id int)";
session.createQuery(hql);
```

and inside this for loop i insert the data from a list into table 'temp' :

```
for(Example example : examples) {
    hql = "insert into temp (" + example.getId() + ")";
    query = session.createQuery(hql);
    query.executeUpdate();
}
```

when i fill the table with the valuse from `examples` (which is a list), then i can use this table for another query. create and insert to this table has to be done automatically in my code and cant do it in database manually because the list `'examples'` is made is the code.

this is what i think about the code, but it does not work. can anybody tell me how i can do this in correct way? thanks.

Comment: are you getting any error if yes then please attach stack trace with question!!!

Comment: @Dev : I get an exception ''unexpected token: create'' . As I guessed creating a table in hibernate is different from what I did. I dont know how to do it. Sorry I cant copy the stack trace here.

Comment: please attach stack-trace It will be really helpful

Comment: I am not allowed to do that. I removed the line `query.executeUpdate();` and now there is no exception but i do not get any results. I searched more about 'create and insert table in hibernate' and seems I have to create .hbm.xml file....

Comment: It's hard to understand why you want to use Hibernate for this task. ORM is for mapping your domain objects to a database layer, but you are creating some temporary, probably arbitrarily defined, objects. Why not use sql for this job?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Hibernate Query Language manage "create" operation. Probably you need to run a native query in using createNativeQuery if you are using EntityManager or createSQLQuery if you are using Hibernate Session:

```
 String hql = "create temporary table temp (id int)";
 session.createSQLQuery(hql).executeUpdate();
```

Comment: what about insert? any idea?

Comment: The insert syntax should be `INSERT INTO TEMP VALUES ('VAL1')`

Comment: to solve the CREATE TABLE you could make a procedure and call it using `call myprocedure()` on a createSQLQuery